# Regarding Indoor Navigation using AR

Tags: ios, augmented-reality, indoor-positioning-system

I am currently doing a AR based ios app for indoor navigation. So how can i create database for multiple floor building and how to use that data for navigation?

Comment: Hi Aspiring Developer, welcome to StackOverflow. It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: No, I just want to know the way to do it. The process. Not Code.

Comment: you can take a look at the  [fantasmo](https://fantasmo.io/home) company, They are building point clouds from images taken with your phone. Then you can use those feature points to localize your device. I would recommend trying ARCore as well but if you have multiple floors ARCore will not work as expected.